# Moment in Vue says that format is not a function

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I have a Vue.js component and am using Moment.js for dates and times.

In the following code, I am setting the value of `eventDate` when the component is mounted.  Later I am using a computed property to retrieve it.  The value displays correctly, but I get a console error saying that `this.eventDate.format` is not a function.  Why?

```
<script>
    import moment from 'moment';

    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                eventDate : ''
            }
        },
        computed : {
            eventShortDate () {
                // console.log(this.eventDate);
                return this.eventDate.format('DD-MM');
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.eventDate = moment(document.getElementById('event-date').innerHTML, 'DD-MM-YY');
        }
    }
</script>
```

The Chrome dev tools says that `eventDate` is an object.  When I `console.log(this.eventDate)` it shows that I have a Moment object.

I tried using the eventDate directly in the Vue template, as `{{ eventDate.format('DD-MM') }}` but again, the value displays correctly but I get the console error.

Comment: I'm not sure when you are rendering the `{{ eventDate.format('DD-MM') }}`, but from the behaviour described, I think it's first applying `.format()` on ''(empty string), before the value of `eventDate` variable is changed on mount, which then triggers another render, causing a successful `.format()`

Comment: Thanks Aman, you are right.  I am now setting the value of eventDate on created(), and it works fine.  Do you want to make your comment in to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template objects (things in `{{ }}` braces) are evaluated before `.mounted()` is called. So, a `.format` call is made on `''` before `.mounted()` can change the `eventDate` value to a moment object. However, once the value is changed in `.mounted()`, it triggers another render which causes the right value to appear.

I recommend trying [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) to conditionally render `{{ eventDate.format('DD-MM') }}` if `eventDate !== ''`, or using the `.created()` event handle.

This Vue.js [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) has a pretty great [diagram](https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png) which I think illustrates pretty well how the Vue lifecycle works.